# TEXTFIELD permitir touch pero no edición Swift

Tags: swift, xcode

suponiendo que tenga un      `textfield`

```
@IBOutlet weak var TypeRegistry: TextField!
```

y este textfield tiene un datepicker

```
let pickerBanks = UIPickerView()
```

y al crear la pantalla haga

```
func createReasonsPickerView()
{
    let toolbar = UIToolbar()
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    let done = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: nil, action: #selector(donePressedEntity))
    toolbar.setItems([done], animated: false)
    self.TypeRegistry.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
    self.TypeRegistry.inputView = pickerReasons
    pickerReasons.delegate = self
    pickerReasons.dataSource = self

}
@objc func donePressedEntity()
{
    self.TypeRegistry.text! = self.selectedEntity.description


    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Pero no quiero que puedan editar , solamente elegir una opcion , como podria realizarlo en swift

probe haciendole isEnable pero no me detecta el click en la caja

Comment: prueba colocando el delegado... UItextViewDelegate... y tiene una funcion llamada textViewShouldBeginEditing... retórnale un false y creo con eso ya no podrán editar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actualización de respuesta:

prueba con lo siguiente:
crea una extension de tu clase donde tengas los textfields que quieres utilizar. normalmente estos se colocan en otro archivo, o al final de tu clase. esta función es precisamente para evitar la edición usando el teclado.

```
      extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
          func textViewShouldBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) -> Bool {
                 return false
}
    }
```

haber si eso te puede ayudar saludos...

Comment: No te entendi bien Yan ,

Comment: dime en donde no comprendiste para poder serte mas claro, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Una solucion muy simple es usar el resingFirstResponder() para que se oculte el teclado y de esa forma no se pueda editar. Con esta solucion podes usar el addTarget() para indicar que ejecute el metodo que abre el picker.

```
class MyClass: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate{

   override func viewDidLoad(){
      ...
      textField.delegate = self
      textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyClass.createReasonsPickerView), for: UIControlEvents.editingDidBegin);
   }

   func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
      textField.resingFirstResponder()
   }

   func createReasonsPickerView(){
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero la verdad es que no me anduvo esta solucion no abre el picker

Comment: Asegurate de poner en el selector el metodo que abre el picker yo puse createReasonPickerView() pero al parecer no es ese el que estas usando. Pero poniendo el metodo correcto en el selector deberia funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

tu textfield es editable solo en simuladores, ya probaste un dispositivo real? esto pasa siempre en emuladores porque tienes acceso al teclado todo el tiempo. Saludos

Comment: Mm no la verdad no eh probado con telefono real , al probar vengo aqui a darte la respeusta